# capto update download fails

Tags: installation, upgrade

I get the following error `Connection to the remote server was lost. Please check your Internet connection. (-1997)`

Anybody know how I can get around this (I don't have problems with anything else)

macbook pro macos sierra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem while trying to upgrade to v1.2.3 just now.  The download failed just as it completed; I suspect something couldn't or wouldn't be written to disc.  I tried downloading from within Capto four times before I gave up.

What I wound up doing was downloading the trial version of v1.2.3 (available at the Capto website) and running it.  It recognized my license and automagically turned into the full version, so all was (and is) well.  Capto also reports that it's now up to date.

I'm not sure what was wrong here, but I've never seen that error before.  I also haven't been able to find out exactly what the error number indicates.  It doesn't seem to have been on anybody's list before 2015, so maybe it's an El Capitan (and, probably, Sierra) thing.